# Why return 0 or 1 in recursive matrix traversal algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, matrix

I've just studied this algorithm for traversing a given matrix using recursion, taken from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/traverse-a-given-matrix-using-recursion/:

> ```cpp
> // C++ program to traverse the matrix recursively 
>
> #include <iostream> 
> using namespace std; 
>
> #define N 2 
> #define M 3 
>
> // Function to traverse the matrix recursively 
> int traverseMatrix(int arr[N][M], int current_row, 
>               int current_col) 
> { 
>   // If the entire column is traversed 
>   if (current_col >= M) 
>       return 0; 
>
>   // If the entire row is traversed 
>   if (current_row >= N) 
>       return 1; 
>
>   // Print the value of the current 
>   // cell of the matrix 
>   cout << arr[current_row][current_col] << ", "; 
>
>   // Recursive call to traverse the matrix 
>   // in the Horizontal direction 
>   if (traverseMatrix(arr, current_row, 
>                   current_col + 1) 
>       == 1) 
>       return 1;
>
>   // Recursive call for changing the 
>   // Row of the matrix 
>   return traverseMatrix(arr, 
>                       current_row + 1, 
>                       0); 
> } 
>
> // Driver code 
> int main() 
> { 
>   int arr[N][M] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, 
>                   { 4, 5, 6 } }; 
>
>   traverseMatrix(arr, 0, 0); 
>   return 0; 
> }
> ```

I just want to understand why they are using `return 1` or `return 0`. What is the purpose?

I tried to understand these returns, but I can't get it...

I'm new to programming. I executed the code and noticed that changing these return values influences the result.

Answer (score 1):

The value 1 signifies that the traversal is complete -- the last row has been traversed -- and that all pending calls in the recursion tree should exit (passing on this message to their caller), as there is nothing more they should do.

The value 0 signifies that there are still more rows to traverse in the matrix.

Note that the value only serves a purpose during the recursion; the main program doesn't care about the returned value -- it would be 1 anyway.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Now it makes sense. thank youu